# Why do I get: Illegal attempt to establish a relationship ... between objects in different contexts

Tags: iphone, core-data

I only have one managed object context.

I have modified the managed object store though.

There are certain fields that I would like to add to every managed object. It would take far too much time to add them all one by one to every object in my system, so I decided to add them programmatically to the managed object model. In the application delegate, I first do:

```
managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];
```

Then I iterate through all the entities in the model and modify them and set the new property array for each one:

```
for (NSEntityDescription *entity in entities) {
    NSAttributeDescription *idAttribute = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
    [idAttribute setName:@"id"];
    [idAttribute setAttributeType:NSStringAttributeType];
    [idAttribute setOptional:NO];
    [idAttribute setIndexed:YES];
```

and so on.

It seems to mostly work fine. I run into problems when I am trying to add an object to a new one-to-one relationship I created. I create the objects from the same managed object context:

```
 self.action = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MobileObjectAction" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
 self.user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MobileUser" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

When I get to

```
 [user setAction:action];
```

I get: 
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'action' between objects in different contexts ...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think my problem might have something to do with the accessors used for programmatically generated core data properties. I suppose I can't use @dynamic anymore since core data does not know about my properties. Can I use @synthesize, or do I have to write the setters and getters myself. If so, what do they need to look like?

Comment: I created my own accessors:
    - (MobileObjectAction *)action {
 [self willAccessValueForKey:@"action"];
 id action = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"action"];
 [self didAccessValueForKey:@"action"];
 return action;
    } 

    - (void)setAction:(MobileObjectAction *)action {
 [self willChangeValueForKey:@"action"];
 [self setPrimitiveValue:action forKey:@"action"];
 [self didChangeValueForKey:@"action"];
    }

but still the same error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put a breakpoint in your code just before the two Entities are related.  Make sure they are both instances of `NSManagedObject`.

If they are, make sure both of them have their `NSManagedObjectContext` set and it is set to the same pointer.

Obviously, make sure they are both valid objects.

Most likely one of the above tests will prove false.

Comment: You are right, the managed object context for one of them is nil. I have no idea why. Here is the code I tried:
 self.action = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MobileObjectAction" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
 self.user = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MobileUser" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

Then I print out the managedObjectContext for both.

The user object has the valid managed object context but the action object just shows 0x0. Why is this happening??

Comment: Clearly at some point the managedObjectContext iVar is nil.  I would put an assertion before both of those calls and catch it when it is nil.  Then you can backtrace it to determine why.

Comment: I got this same exception when I was mistakenly counting on isDeleted to return YES for a cascade-deleted object. Checking whether the object returned a nil context, as suggested here, proved more reliable. I’m a little confused why isDeleted didn’t do the job, but very happy to have a solution. Thanks for the post and the clear answer.

Comment: @Mike, how did you solved your problem with `nil` pointer in `managedObjectContext`?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem and solve it:

- one context (no splitting/merging).
- set property -> and get "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship  between objects..."

so - **W** ha **T** 's wrong and what I mast **F** ound and correct?

answer is simply:
before

```
[meeting setCreator:    [self currentUser]];
```

after

```
[meeting setCreator:    _currentUser];
```

and for info

*.h

```
@interface{
 Person*     _currentUser;
}
@property (readonly, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
- (Person*)currentUser;
```

*.m

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext        = _managedObjectContext;

- (Person*)currentUser{
    return _currentUser;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {

if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (coordinator != nil) {
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
}
return _managedObjectContext;
}
```